# Make flash-movie full browser size?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to create a small flash-app, which needs to run as big as possible on the browser. For example regexr and Grooveshark work this way. However, if I use the `File -> Publish Settings` and there set the width and height 100%, it resizes to full browser, but...

When I use stageHeight and stageWidth, they don't change. I only have one frame in my animation, so should I fire a `eventListener` for something like "resize"?

I've just started actionscript 3 so please don't provide too advanced stuff, at least without explaining.

Thanks,
Martti Laine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right -- there is, in fact, a [resize event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/Stage.html#event%3aresize) to listen for. For the stage to resize properly, though, you'll want to set the stage's [`scaleMode`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/Stage.html#scaleMode) and [`align`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/Stage.html#align) properties.

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;    // Use NO_SCALE then resize your content manually to avoid stretching/pixelation
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;            // So that (0, 0) is always in the top-left corner

stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeOccurred);

function resizeOccurred(e:Event):void
{
    trace("New stage width: " + stage.stageWidth + "; new stage height: " + stage.stageHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By full browser size do you actually mean fullscreen?

If yes add this listener to stage too:

```
stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, resizeHandler);
```

Interestingly Flash doesn't consider going to fullscreen as a normal resize. And don't forget about imports on the top of your class:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.FullScreenEvent;
```

Otherwise I agree with Cameron.